# CodeIgniter controller instantiation: when does it happen?

Tags: codeigniter

i'd like to know a details about when instantiation happens in CodeIgniter, specifically that of controllers.

Let's say i have a controller called Main which is structured like this:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller{

 public $variable;

 public function index(){

    $this->load->view('home/body');
    $this->variable="TEST";

 }

 public function run(){
     do something with $this->variable;
 }

}
```

Let's say i call on the browser *localhost/index.php/main*, thus instantiating for the first main the controller *Main*. Its default method index() simply loads an html page via *load->view()*.

In this page, there's a button which makes an AJAX request to the same controller to use the method *run()*, using the url *localhost/index.php/main/run*.

At this point, will *$variable* be undefined? In other words, will the *Main* class be re-instantiated, or will the AJAX request use the same instance built before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your confusion. Often times with the singleton pattern in codeigniter it seems like variables will exist in perpetuity. That is not the case.

The AJAX load on `run()` is essentially a separate request (think of it as a page refresh). Any variables previously defined in `index()` or only defined in the *request for `index()`* will not be available.

**You have 3 options to carry over variables from one call to the next: sessions, cookies, or database.**